# How to get rid of ISBLANK extra spaces in number app?

Tags: macos, excel-formula, numbers

This is on Numbers on Mac: I generate a paragraph of text from a row where columns hold parts of text. However, as some cells are empty, I had to use conditional ISEMPTY for the formula to work:

```
""&B9&" "&IF(ISBLANK(C9);"";C9)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(D9);"";D9)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(E9);"";E9)&" "&IF(ISBLANK(F9);"";F9)&" "&G9&" "&H9&""
```

This does function, but I end up with double spaces in areas where I have one or more columns empty (so the spaces double).

Is there a way I could use an another conditional like ISEMPTY(ISEMPTY...) to get rid of those?

This is not a huge problem, but is annoying and time consuming, because I have to fix these texts afterwards (there is a lot of them). :-(

Comment: TRIM in Excel will remove multiple spaces between words (as well as leading and trailing spaces). Does it behave the same way in Numbers ? Online references are pretty scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parts with `&" "&` from `IF(ISBLANK(C9);"";C9)&" "&`into `IF(ISBLANK(C9);"";C9&" ")&`
In your formula you check if `C9` is blank. Whether blank or not it's followed by a `" "` space. So if blank you get a space added, but no data prior to it. If the next is empty too, you get another space without data etc..
By including the `&" "` inside the if statement it will only add a space if `C9` is not blank. Blank cell adds no data and no space.

Comment: Thanks you, it worked perfectly. I wont say I understand it tho.

Comment: Explained it in my answer. Hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(B9;" ";C9;" ";D9;" ";E9;" ";F9;" ";G9;" ";H9))
```

Maybe you should learn about TEXTJOIN..

Comment: Unfortunately there is no TEXTJOIN function on Mac. I tried importing from Excel, but it didn't work.